# Postgresql extract week

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why when I run

```
select (EXTRACT(WEEK FROM current_date)::int )
```

The output is `6` - why?

Today is `2016-02-14` which is the `8th` week since the start of this year.

Am I getting this result wrong?

I'm looking for a function which I give it date and it tells me what week of the year this date is.

Comment: Is the date in your computer set correctly?

Comment: For which version of postgresql ?

Comment: Postgres is right, 2016-02-14 is in week 6: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) is pretty clear on the calculation:

> week
>
> The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By
>   definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year
>   contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of
>   a year is in week 1 of that year.
>
> In the ISO week-numbering system, it is possible for early-January
>   dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and
>   for late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year.
>   For example, 2005-01-01 is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and
>   2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while 2012-12-31 is
>   part of the first week of 2013. It's recommended to use the isoyear
>   field together with week to get consistent results.

Weeks start on a Monday, so Sunday is the end of a week (and "today" is Sunday where I am and in most of the world at this particular time).  Also, the first week depends on the when the year starts.